# Cómo tratar objeto retornado en una consulta LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, objeto

tengo una función que me retorna las filas de un `dataGridView` que están seleccionadas mediante una columna de `checkBoxs`:

```
public static object RetornaSeleccionatsGrid(DataGridView dgv)
{

    var values =
    from DataGridViewRow row in dgv.Rows
    where Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells["colCheck"].Value) == true
    select new { id = row.Cells[1].Value, nombre = row.Cells[2].Value };
    return values.toList();
}
```

El problema es que el objeto que me retorna, no sé tratarlo. Es decir, hasta ahora, lo asignaba al `dataSource` de un `DataGridView` con el método `toList()` por que solo necesitaba mostrar los datos y me quedaba tan ancho, pero ahora, necesito tratar esos datos y no sé cómo hacerlo.
El objeto por lo que veo es de tipo:

```
{System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator<System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRow, <>f__AnonymousType0<object, object>>}
```

Me podéis echar un cable? como puedo tratar ese objeto, o como puedo castearlo
Muchas gracias.
La salida del objeto:

```
+       [0] { id = "01", nombre = "Familia 01                                        " }    <Anonymous Type>
+       [1] { id = "02", nombre = "Familia 02                                        " }    <Anonymous Type>
+       [2] { id = "05", nombre = "FamsenseSub                                       " }    <Anonymous Type>
+       Raw View
```

Comment: Podrías poner la salida de ese proceso?
Alguna captura del debug o tratar de imprimir por consola.

Comment: He editado mi comentario, ¿ es eso lo que me pedias ?

Comment: en el select new puedes ponerno declarando un nuevo elemento, para esto debes tener definida la clase con las propiedades id y nombre.  new Familia()
        {
            Id= (int)row.Cells[1].Value,
            Familia= (string)row.Cells[2].Value,
             
        };

Comment: Ok, no me había percatado de que tienes un .toList(). Con eso ya estás devolviendo el objeto como un tipo List, por eso te devuelve posiciones, pero de tipo Anónimo porque lo definiste con var, en vez de asignarlo con "var values", intenta con: List<object> values = CONSULTA;

Y ya podrías intentar accesar a los elementos así porque te está devolviendo una lista de objetos:

values[0]["id"];
values[0]["nombre"];

Comment: Perfecto! Gracias a los dos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando en el linq defines un `new` sin declarar una clase estas retornando un `objeto anonimo`.

[Tipos anónimos (Guía de programación de C#)](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/anonymous-types)

esto es importante porque no se usa con el `object` sino con el `dymanic`, pero es complicado si despues quieres vincular este objeto a otro componente, es por eso que no se recomienda usarlo para retornar datos de esa forma.

Podrias definir una class como ser

```
public class ResultItem
{
   public int Id {get;set;}
   public int Nombre {get;set;}
}
```

Pero en tu caso solo retornas un unica instancia por eso se usa el `First()` o el `FirstOrDefault()`

```
public static ResultItem RetornaSeleccionatsGrid(DataGridView dgv)
{

    var row = dgv.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
                         .FirstOrDefault(x=> Convert.ToBoolean(x.Cells["colCheck"].Value));
                         
    ResultItem item = null;
    
    if(row != null)
    {
        item = new ResultItem()
        {
            Id = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells["id"].Value),
            Nombre = Convert.ToString(row.Cells["nombre"].Value),
        };
    }
    
    return item;
}
```

de esta forma tomas la row seleccionada, validando que exista alguna con el check, sino retorna null